# Ascending order of fetched data

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[image]

I am fetching count. My target is to display it in ASCENDING ORDER. i have tried to sort it using sort($match); but i have still failed to achieve my goal. Thank you. Any help will be appreciated

Controller:

```
function asdasdas(){
            $entry= $this->repo->entryfetch();
            
            
            
            $data='<table>
    <thead><tr><th>NO. </th></tr></thead>';
          
            
            foreach($entry as $entry){
                
                $match= $this->repo->matchfetch($entry->handlerID);
                
                $data.='<thead><tr><th><hr>'.$entry->handlerID.'&nbsp;'.$entry->entryName.'</th> ';
     
             
                
                foreach($match as $match){
                    
                    $diff = $match->weightM - $match->weightW;
                    
                    if($match->handlerIDM === $entry->handlerID){
                        $name=$match->handlertestW;
                        $count=$match->countM;
                    }else{
                        
                        $name=$match->handlerM;
                        $count=$match->countW;
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    $data.='<tbody><tr><td>'.$count.'</td>';
               
                    $data.='<td></td></tr></tbody>';
    //             
                }
               
                
            }
            
            $data .='<table>';
          
            echo $data;
```

sort($match); // i have tried to sort it using this but it is not working.
}

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array from the last index to 0

```
function asdasdas()
{
    $entry = $this->repo->entryfetch();
    $data = '<table>
    <thead><tr><th>NO. </th></tr></thead>';

    for ($j = count($entry) - 1; $j >= 0; $j--) {
        $match = $this->repo->matchfetch($entry[$j]->handlerID);
        $data .= '<thead><tr><th><hr>' . $entry[$j]->handlerID . '&nbsp;' . $entry[$j]->entryName . '</th> ';

        for ($i = count($match) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $diff = $match[$i]->weightM - $match[$i]->weightW;
            if ($match[$i]->handlerIDM === $entry[$j]->handlerID) {
                $name = $match[$i]->handlertestW;
                $count = $match[$i]->countM;
            } else {
                $name = $match[$i]->handlerM;
                $count = $match[$i]->countW;
            }
            $data .= '<tbody><tr><td>' . $count . '</td>';
            $data .= '<td></td></tr></tbody>';
        }
    }
    $data .= '<table>';
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement your code and it is not working. Did i miss anything? :( 

Test1: https://prnt.sc/26uzjhy

Comment: Test2: https://prnt.sc/26uzjsa

Comment: I notice the errors in your code, in the `foreach` loops you shouldn't use the same name after `as` fix them

Comment: and do the same for the table head `for($j = count($entry )-1; $j >= 0; $j--)` , and change `$entry` to `$entry[$j]`

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm getting confused. Is it okay for me to ask you to add your recommendation to your codes? Thank you.

Comment: I edit my answer, check it.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. It is still error. https://prnt.sc/26v1b1e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241973/discussion-between-yazan-fouad-aldbaisy-and-dark).

Comment: Sorry, i slept already last night. Are you still available for now? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Context is not much clear. Do you need to sort $match before for loop or while inside the forloop. Can you explain a bit if haven't got the solution.